# How to show "-" when the query results nothing between table

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I'm running on a car budget project which is need a table link process under mysql. Because of the display limited so I need to gather every needed information from some tables to show in a summary table.

Some of the information might be blanked and I need it to display "-" instead of empty cell.

Here's my table:

**car_db**

```
c_id    c_brand    c_ver    c_buy_date
--------------------------------------
1       toyota     camry    2013-04-20
2       nissan     teana    2013-04-15
3       toyota     soluna   2013-04-10
4       honda      accord   2013-04-10
```

**car_bal**

```
cb_id    cb_cid    cb_cost    c_repair
--------------------------------------
1        4         150000     20000
2        3         100000     15500
```

*while cb_cid=car_db.c_id

When a car_db table is displayed, I expected:

```
Car ID    Brand/Model      Bought On    Cost     Repair    Total Cost
1         Toyota Camry     2013-04-20   -        -         -
2         Nissan Teana     2013-04-15   -        -         -
3         Toyota Soluna    2013-04-10   100000   15500     115500
4         Honda Accord     2013-04-10   150000   20000     170000
```

So I wrote:

```
select 
concat(car_db.c_brand,'-',car_db.c_ver) as brand,
car_db.c_buy_date as buy_date,
car_bal.cb_cost as cost1,
car_bal.cb_repair as repair,
(sum(car_bal.cb_cost) + sum(car_bal.cb_repart)) as sum
from car_db
inner join car_bal on car_db.cb_id=car_bal.cb_cid
order by car_db.c_id desc
```

I tested these codes with several errors. So I need some suggestions :

1. How to display "-" instead of empty cell in a table.
2. I don't need any help of PHP, just finish it in MySQL.
3. Is there anyway to ease or shorten my MySQL codes?

Answer (score 1):

```
ifnull(sum(car_bal.cb_cost),'-')
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename 
-> MODIFY colname NOT NULL DEFAULT '-';
```